# Simple HTML not shown in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have simple HTML file in my computer:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Microsoft Corporation</title>
ddd
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Google Chrome show it as not HTML page and includes some garbage:

```
<�html> <�body> <�head> <�title>Microsoft Corporation<�/title> ddd <�/head> 
<�/body> <�/html>
```

THis is how it looks in notepad++:
[image]

Comment: There could be some malware issue with your machine.

Comment: How's your encoding set up in Notepad++? Look under tab `Encoding` in the menu bar. It should be `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Microsoft Corporation</title>
</head>
<body>
ddd
</body>
</html>
```

You should have opened body of the html page then put your content in it.

Comment: though it's a good practice but that doesn't create this kinda issue

Answer (score 0):

Your html syntax is incorrect. Write the following sample html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Save the file as **index.html** and then open the file using any browser. It will display "Hello World" on the window.